# Trim the length of a number in plsql and keep it constant

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

How do I trim a number variable to keep its length constant in PL/SQL.

For eg: I have a field `customerId`  of `NUMBER`  type . Now I have a  mask function where I want to pass only the first 6 digits of this `customerId`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to pass only the first 6 digits of this customerId.

Use **SUBSTR** to extract the first 6 digits and then convert it back to number using**TO_NUMBER**.

```
TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(customerId, 1, 6))
```

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(1234567890, 1, 6)) MY_NUM FROM DUAL;

    MY_NUM
----------
    123456
```

Comment: @codeLearner You're welcome. Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query as well. Implicit conversions work in this case, no need to apply to_number again.

```
select substr(customer_id, 1, 6) from dual;
```

Comment: *Implicit* conversion comes into picture, when further number operation is carried over with it. Otherwise, `SUBSTR()` will always return a string as the name implies.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, implicit conversions will have negative impacts in where clause. As per my understanding, there will not be impact in select clause.

Comment: `select 1 MY_NUM ,'1' MY_NUM FROM DUAL;` try it out in `SQL*Plus`

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju What I wanted to say Mahesh already explained. Implicit conversion will happen when the data type conversion would happen. Here you are just selecting. But if OP wants numeric calculation/arithmetic, then you should explicitly convert it to number.

Comment: I always consider this sort of implicit conversion to be a code smell - i.e. there's nothing in the code above that implies that `customer_id` is a number - if this code were written by a good developer, `customer_id` should be a string type since it is being passed unconverted to SUBSTR, which expects a string.